# Insert newline before/after match for TSV

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I'm going grey trying to figure out how to accomplish some regex matching to insert new lines. Example input/output below...

Example TSV Data:

```
Name    Monitoring  Tags
i-RBwPyvq8wPbUhn495 enabled "some:tags:with:colons=some:value:with:colons-and-dashes/and/slashes/yay606-values-001  some:other:tag:with-colons-and-hypens=MACHINE NAME  Name=NAMETAG    backup=true"
i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01  backup=true Name=SOMENAME"
```

Desired Output:

```
Name    Monitoring  Tags
i-RBwPyvq8wPbUhn495 enabled "some:tags:with:colons=some:value:with:colons-and-dashes/and/slashes/yay606-values-001
some:other:tag:with-colons-and-hyphens=MACHINE NAME 
Name=NAMETAG    
backup=true"
i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01  
backup=true 
Name=SOMENAME"
```

I can guarantee each `key=value` within those quotes are separated by hard/literal tabs, although it may not appear that way with how the StackOverflow code block is displayed in HTML they did carry over into the code block editor, the data under the column `Tags` is in quotes so that even though they are tab separated they stay within the `Tags` column. For whatever reason I'm not able to successfully get the desired results.

In my measly attempts, I've been basically capturing everything between the `""` as if tabs aren't separated in my regex searches because of my use of wildcards `[TAB].*=.*[TAB]` is obviously not working because then I'm losing everything in between the first/last occurrence for each line. I've attempted storing them in capture groups without any success.

I'm looking for a unix toolset solution (sed, awk, perl and the like). Any/All help is appreciated!

Comment: Tested with your string and looks like this could work: `sed -re 's/\t+/\n/g' test.txt`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz that will add a new line for all tabs/columns, I only want new lines within the tags column. I tested what you provided and although it does get close (new lines are added before each tab in the tags column), it also ruins the rest of the data.

Comment: Are you just trying to replace tabs with newlines when they're within double quotes?

Comment: @EdMorton I think that's a safe scenario to go with, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/".*"/){str=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/\t/,"\n",str); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) str substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file
Name    Monitoring      Tags
i-RBwPyvq8wPbUhn495 enabled "some:tags:with:colons=some:value:with:colons-and-dashes/and/slashes/yay606-values-001
some:other:tag:with-colons-and-hypens=MACHINE NAME
Name=NAMETAG
backup=true"
i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01
backup=true
Name=SOMENAME"
```

It just extracts a string between `"`s from the current record, replaces all tabs with newlines within that string, then puts the record back together before it's printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed (GNU sed) 4.4

```
sed -E ':A;s/(".*)\t(.*")/\1\n\2/;tA' TSV_Data_File
```

With OSX sed, you can try this one.
I think the \t is ok.

```
sed -E '
:A
s/(".*)\t(.*")/\1\
\2/
tA
' TSV_Data_File
```

brief explain :

Catch the text inside "

Substitute the last \t by \n

If a substitution occur jump to A else continue

With awk :

awk -v RS='"' 'NR%2==0{gsub("\t","\n")}1' ORS='"' TSV_Data_File

Comment: Brilliant, it does indeed work! Can you please break down and describe the expression? Curious how it works on multiple matches as it does even though you apparently only use two capture groups?

Comment: Also, I'd be curious if anyone can make this work with OSX sed, this works fine with GNU sed, but if it could more portable that would be great.

Comment: this is the portable version I think: `sed -e ':A;s/\("[^\t]*\)\t\(.*"\)/\1\n\2/;tA' test.txt`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz `\n` is not portable, unfortunately.

Comment: amazing! didn't know that

Comment: The portable way to use a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline character.

Comment: how about using \r in MacOSX?

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, but for some reason that isn't working with this answer...unless I'm just breaking it some other way in trying that.

Comment: TryTryAgain - I highly doubt if any of the sed scripts we've seen so far are portable, as soon as you veer of `s/old/new/` with sed you're going down the rabbit hole of non-portable constructs. Event `\t` is non-portable - you need a literal tab character for portability.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz `\r` is a completely different character from `\n` and is usually only present in line-endings when combined with `\n` to form a newline string of `\r\n` (e.g. as used by Windows). Idk for sure if/how to represent `\r` in a portable sed script but I expect you'd need to enter the literal control character that `\r` represents (e.g. `control-V control-M`).

Comment: @EdMorton used to be the Mac line ending. If the script is for Mac then it could be crafted for it and not necessarily portable. Anyway, interesting exercise.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz good to know but in any case for portability with sed you need to use literal characters, not the escape sequences that we typically use to represent them.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically *ctac_'s* `awk` answer converted to perl:

```
perl -pe'1 while s/(".*)\t(.*")/$1\n$2/s' file.tsv
```

Where the `\t` might be replaced by `\t\s*` if you want just one newline out of each tab-and-then-some.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+=\S\+/\n&/2g' file
```

Insert a newline in before the second or more non-empty strings containing an `=`.